# Buttons not showing up in ExtJS message box

Tags: extjs

I am an ExtJS beginner, below is the very simple code fragment taken from a tutorial:

```
<head>
 <title>Getting Started Example</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
   href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
 <script src="extjs/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
 <script src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
 <script>
  Ext.onReady(function(){

   Ext.Msg.show({
    title:'Milton',
    msg:'Have you seen my stapler?',
    buttons:{
    yes:true,
    no:true,
    cancel:true
       }
     });
  });
</script>
</head>
```

It just occurs to me that none of the buttons will show in the message box, could any experts help me debug? I've checked a lot of times and code is exactly the same as tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any errors in firebug or chrome console.

Comment: I think there is an apostrophe after no:true', remove that and try.

Comment: Upvoted just cause of the Office Space reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

       Ext.Msg.show({
        title:'Milton',
        msg:'Have you seen my stapler?',
        buttons: Ext.MessageBox.YESNOCANCEL
         });
  });
```

Comment: Ext.MessageBox.YESNOCANCEL is standard configuration for YES/NO/CANCEL buttons given in Ext.MessageBox class.